# Why can't I log into minecraft with a mojang account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

I created a Mojang account and downloaded the Minecraft launcher, but when I started it up, I couldn't log in. Since the log in fields did not require a username, I tried typing in my email, and still couldn't log in. I've tried after resetting my password, but that didn't work either. What am I supposed to do to log in and play?

Comment: Where didnt it ask for a username? when you created the account or when you logged in?

Answer (score 13):

Mojang accounts are not Minecraft accounts. You can get a Mojang account for free (it requires no username), but you must actually buy Minecraft to play it. When you buy Minecraft, you will be asked for a username.